# How to stop whatsapp from interpreting string as hyperlink

Tags: android, hyperlink, whatsapp

In my android app, I have a feature to share some information. I use an intent (plain text) to share the information in whatever way the user chooses (Whatsapp, E-mail etc). Now, the string I have contains a phrase like "foo.me". If this is shared via whatsapp, it is regarded as an hyperlink to the domain https://foo.me. However, I do not want whatsapp to think that this is a link.

What options do I have to prevent whatsapp from making the part of the string clickable? Sure, I could enter a space between the "." and the "me", but I do not want that (only if nothing else works). Are there any hidden special symbols I could add in the string, so that it does not look like a URL or tell whatsapp in any way that this is not a URL (escape characters)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your string into [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section.

Comment: This changes nothing, unfortunately. It is still clickable.